# StrongTypingException when setting column value

Tags: c#, .net, strongly-typed-dataset

Can anyone please tell me why I get a StrongTypingException when ASSIGNING a value to a column in a strongly typed DataTable? (I understand why I get it if I were to READ the column with DBNull value)

In the example below I'm trying to assign a value from one DataTable to another (all columns in the example are of type **Int32**). I can assign a value to the 'newOrderRow.items' column but when I do the same with the 'newOrderRow.debcode' column an Exception is thrown! Why?!

***Some of the things I've tried so far (without any luck):***
- Assign hard coded value instead of 'calclineRow.debcode'
- Call newOrderRow.SetdebcodeNull() before assigning another value
- Changed DefaultValue property on 'debcode' column in 'orderrows' table from DBNull to -1 and *it STILL throws the Exception and says it's DBNull !!!*

```
myDataSet.orderrowsRow newOrderRow;

foreach (MyDataSet.calclinesRow calclineRow in myDataSet.calclines)
{
    newOrderRow = myDataSet.orderrows.NeworderrowsRow();  //Create new 'orderrows' row

    //Assign values from one DataTable to another
    if (!calclineRow.IsitemsNull())
        newOrderRow.items = calclineRow.items;  //calclineRow.items == 1. Assignment successful
    if (!calclineRow.IsdebcodeNull()) 
        newOrderRow.debcode = calclineRow.debcode; //calclineRow.debcode == 556. Assignment raises System.Data.StrongTypingException ! (See message below)


    myDataSet.orderrows.AddorderrowsRow(newOrderRow);
}

/*Exception Message:
=====================

System.Data.StrongTypingException: The value for column 'debcode' in table 'orderrows' is DBNull. 
---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. 
at MyProject.MyDataSet.orderrowsRow.get_debcode() in Q:\MyProjFolder\DataSets\MyDataSet.Designer.cs:line 21680
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. Sorry, my bad.

I forgot that I was doing things with the 'debcode' column in the OnColumnChanging event handler on my DataTable. When I disabled that it all worked as it should.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the auto-generated `SetNull` methods if the nullable property is null:

```
if (!calclineRow.IsitemsNull())
    newOrderRow.items = calclineRow.items;  
else
    newOrderRow.SetitemsNull();

if (!calclineRow.IsdebcodeNull()) 
    newOrderRow.debcode = calclineRow.debcode; 
else
    newOrderRow.SetdebcodeNull();
```

You also have to ad the new `DataRow` to the table in the loop since `NeworderrowsRow` does this not automatically.

```
myDataSet.orderrows.AddNeworderrowsRow(newOrderRow);
```

The line where the exception occurs(MyDataSet.Designer.cs:line 21680) suggests that it's raised from an auto-generated method of the `DataSet` which reads this property. Since you haven't used `SetdebcodeNull` it does not know that it's null and throws the `StrongTypingException` when it tries to read it.

Comment: No, thats not where my problem is. The problem is that 'calclineRow.debcode' is NOT DBNull. It has a value of 556 but when I try to assign that value to 'newOrderRow.debcode' the program complains about 'newOrderRow.debcode' is DBNull. 
(Which of course it is, that's why I'm trying to assign a value to it! Stupid .NET!)

Comment: Why are you overriding `newOrderRow` always in the loop? Instead of "reusing" an outer variable, create it in the loop. `orderrows newOrderRow = myDataSet.orderrows.NeworderrowsRow();` I'm not sure if this causes the issue. And you have to add new  row to the `DataTable` since `NeworderrowsRow` does this not implicitely.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Added some more  of the code to clarify. Anyway, this hasn't much to do with the actual problem that we're discussing here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
if (!calclineRow.IsdebcodeNull()) 
    newOrderRow["debcode"] = calclineRow.debcode;
```

While I admit it doesn't make a lot of sense, it appears as if calling the `Set` for newOrderRow.debcode has the effect of calling the `Get`, which as noted throws an exception if the underlying property is DbNull.

Comment: You should probably examine the generated code for your dataset.  I'm wondering if something weird is going on.

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I even tried rebuilding it by right clicking on the .xsd-file in the Solution Explorer in VS2010 and choosing 'Run custom tool' (But I don't know if that really re-generates the code behind of the DataSet?)